# Ergodicity in Césaro mean : deterministic and stochastic cases

Tags: stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

Let $\{ X_t, t \geq 0 \}$ be a $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued stochastic process on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

**Assumption**

- $X_t$ is a regenerative process in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_process
- for all functions $f$ continuous and bounded on $\mathbb{R}^d$ 
  $$
  \lim_{t \to\infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t \mathbb{E} f(X_s) \mbox{d} s = \nu(f)
  $$
  with $s \to \mathbb{E}(f(X_s))$ is measurable and where $\nu$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

**Question**

How to get rid of the expectation? In the sense,
$$
\lim_{t \to\infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(X_s) \mbox{d} s = \nu(f), \: \mbox{a.s.}
$$
I would like to avoid the renewal reward theorem.

Comment: What if $X_t$ is a process that starts at a random position, and never moves?

Comment: Could you please specify your assumptions on the stochastic process $\{X_t, t \ge 0\}$? In the current form of your question I can't see why the function $s \mapsto \mathbb{E}f(X_s)$ should be measurable.

Comment: Thank you Anthony Quas and Jochen Glueck for your remarks. I am not sure what type of minimal assumption on $X$ would make $s \to \mathbb{E} f(X_s)$ measurable. I think we can assume it. Furthermore, I would like to add that $X_t$ is a regenerative process in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_process.